# Creating an array INSIDE an array in the mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I want to create an array of stores. And in each store, there would be sections. So one store maybe have a deli and produce section. Another store may just cashiers and a meat section.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  store: {
    type: Array,
  },
  section: { // how do I put this inside the store array?
    type: Array, 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

we can do it by by specifying type  mixed, it will accept any kind of data structre

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  store: [{
        type: Schema.Types.Mixed
    }]
});
```